# How to get last Sunday including today in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, date

Is it possible to get last Sunday in PostgreSQL including today's day?

For example if today is Sunday expression returns today's date. If today is other day it returns nearest last Sunday.

Comment: What have you tried so far? What data type are you working with?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Try this:

```
select current_date - extract(dow from current_date)::integer;
```

Sunday is 0 in Postgres, so this date adjustment is exactly what you describe.